# CAPABILITY_NAMED_IAM using cloud9

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, serverless, aws-cloud9, awsdeploy

I am trying to do all my dev work using cloud9 template for serverless apps
It complains that i don't have  CAPABILITY_NAMED_IAM due to the fact that I am creating a role. How do I edit cloud9 deploy defaults to include  CAPABILITY_NAMED_IAM?

Answer (score 0):

If you started your Cloud9 with Code star, you can modify the pipeline to enable capabilities to CAPABILITY_NAMED_IAM in the AWS management console.
You need to edit the GenerateChangeSet section in the deploy step.

Otherwhise you should look into your create/update stack to add the --capabilities CAPABILITY_NAMED_IAM :

```
cloudformation create-stack --stack-name my-stack --template-url dummy-template.yaml --role-arn ... --tags ... --capabilities CAPABILITY_NAMED_IAM
```

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/APIReference/API_CreateStack.html
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/using-iam-template.html#using-iam-capabilities

Comment: Thanks will look into it.  Was hoping deploy step in Cloud9 was configurable in config file to add --capabilities CAPABILITY_NAMED_IAM . Will try your suggestions.